# in case of empty class sizeof object is 1 bytes, but in case of non empty class sizeof object is not equals to size of class members + 1

Tags: c++

consider the below code

```
class akay
{
};
int main() 
{
    akay object1;
    cout<<"[output] size of "<<sizeof(object1)<<endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

in this case output is `[output] size of 1`
now consider below code

```
class akay
{
    int i;
};
int main() 
{
    akay object1;
    cout<<"[output] size of "<<sizeof(object1)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

in this case output is `[output] size of 4`

We now that in case of empty class, 1 bytes storage is allocated to the object. I want to know that in case of non empty class size of object is equal to the sum of size of members in the class where this one extra bytes is utilized.

Anyone who knows the answer please provide with some ref.

Comment: C doesn't have classes. Why do you spam the C tag watchers?

Comment: *in case of non empty class sizeof object is not equals to size of class members + 1* - why do you expect that?

Comment: The only reason that an empty class has size 1 instead of size 0 is so that when you have an array of empty-class objects, each object in the array will still have its own unique address.  Non-empty class-objects will always have unique addresses regardless, so there is no need for the compiler to add an additional byte to them.

Comment: Here is the reference you asked for https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf section 6.7.2.8.

Answer (score 0):

The size of an empty class needs to be at least one, because otherwise, you could not have an array.

The size of any class, is the sum of all of the members of the class, plus a bit.

Processors have been faster when loading an 8 byte double, when it fits on an 8 byte boundary.  So padding is introduced into a class, to make sure each of its members are aligned to the correct boundary.

The algorithm for this means you could lose nearly half of the space of the raw members with alignment.,

Comment: The "plus a bit" (for a class with no bases and no virtual functions) is the sum of the padding needed by each member to ensure proper alignment.   If it is possible for all members to be properly aligned without any padding, then no padding is needed.